# Sour Dough Starter - proofing in less than 24 hours?

Tags: sourdough

I recently started with making sour dough. I created a new starter yesterday. After feeding it one time in less than 24 hours it's already doubling it's size. I'm not using self-rising flour just normal wheat bread flour.

Is it usual that it picked up so fast?

Comment: So you just fed an existing starter leftover? Or you started from scratch with just flour and water?

Comment: Did same on Sunday. Used wheat flour type 2000. It's normal for such flour to double (or even triple) in size in first 24 hours (especially in calm, warm place). I assume it's due to amount of wild yeast and airness of the flour itself.

Comment: @Luciano just flour and water, no existing starter. Bare in mind I live in Singapore, our humidity is 85% and temps is about 29 - 32 C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

24 hours is above average but not unheard of, 24 hours is a realistic time. I'd say you have a healthy starter on your hands.

Answer (score 0):

Temperature can make a big difference. In my house right now the air temp is around 65F depending on the room or area, which is pretty low for sourdough.  I leave my starter on the counter and it rises slowly.

I am fortunate to have an oven which can go down to 85-90F, at this temp the difference in activity is very noticeable, I would say it is 3 or 4 times as active, and I can easily get the starter to double in a few hours.

Other factors that make a difference are the quality and type of water, chlorine and other additives can inhibit activity, also the freshness and type of flour, etc.

Comment: The OP seems to be saying that they created a starter *from scratch in less than 24 hours*.

Answer (score 0):

I think to get the most of your starter however you should go through the complete process 5 - 7 days just to get a starter that is really sour.